# Bash: working with linenumbers to use them in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Basically i just need to uncomment two lines containing a specific string.
Therefore i grep the string to get the line numbers and use sed to uncomment
(sure one might also use sed to get line numbers but the problem is the same).

You get the line numbers each on its own line, i dont know how to work with the line numbers sitting on its own line, so im trying to to get them into one line to use bash variables to handle the line numbers:

```
$ cat configfile
some text
    #a string foo
    #b string bar
some other text
#more text
much more text
```

so my first try is:

```
linenr=$(grep -n string configfile | cut -d: -f1)     # get line numbers (several lines)
linenr=(${linenr//\ / })                              # put line numbers into one line
sed -i "${linenr[0]},${linenr[1]} s/##*//" configfile # uncomment lines
```

my second try is:

```
linenr=$(sed -n '/string/=' configfile)               # get line numbers (several lines)
linenr=$(echo $linenr | sed -i 's/\n/ /' configfile)  # put line numbers into one line
sed -i "${linenr[0]},${linenr[1]} s/##*//" configfile # uncomment lines
```

I need to do this twice, for two nearly similar configfiles and for some reason, i get different output of the line numbers, altough the code is the same for both configfiles: (works for configfile4 but not for configfile6? i assume the content of those files is irrelevant for the output of the found line numbers? also checked line endings, are same in both files)

```
configfile4lines:
44 45
configfile6lines:
54
55
```

how should one work in such situtions with line numbers or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regexp match as the address in `sed`, instead of line numbers.

```
sed -i '/string/s/##*//' configfile
```

Comment: ok since this works better, i wanted to use this for other strings too, but for those strings there are configuration examples which i dont want to uncomment. is there a way to exclude lines with string 'example' from found lines before uncommenting? or should i define those examples in another way in configfiles?

Comment: If you get more complex than this, `sed` is probably not the right tool. Use `awk` or `perl`.